# The method is not called in the Twilio-chat file

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

Js file: twilio-chat

Method: notifyMemberJoined and notifyMemberLeft at

Problem: The user does not call when closing the chat tab, I don't know why

According to the case of the official website, it can be called normally when the typeing is notified, but the two just sent are not called.

```
function initChannelEvents() {

        tc.currentChannel.on('messageAdded', tc.addMessageToList);
        tc.currentChannel.on('typingStarted', showTypingStarted);
        tc.currentChannel.on('typingEnded', hideTypingStarted);
        tc.currentChannel.on('memberJoined', notifyMemberJoined);
        tc.currentChannel.on('memberLeft', notifyMemberLeft);
        $inputText.prop('disabled', false).focus();

        utils.logInfo('Channel ' + tc.channelName + ' joined successfully!');
    }

    function notifyMemberJoined(member) {
        notify(member.identity + ' joined the channel');
    }

    function notifyMemberLeft(member) {
        notify(member.identity + ' left the channel');
    }
```

User does not prompt to leave the channel

Comment: I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding what your question is. Are you saying that when you close a tab the `notifyMemberLeft` event does not fire in other tabs?